# Facebook APP with Shared SSL in codeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, hosting, ssl-certificate, facebook-apps

I have a host with shared ssl in hostgator.com, I uploaded codeIgniter site in public_html(root) directory. I want to develop a website as well as facebook application.
website run successful with 'login with facebook' while running a facebook app, it gives an url redirect error.

This is http url

```
 url(Website): http://example.org/
```

and secure url is

```
 https://in9.hostgator.in/~username/
```

In facebook app configuration,

```
  canvas url :  http://example.org/
  Secure Canvas URL : https://in9.hostgator.in/~username/ (Work in url)
```

When i have run facebook application, facebook gives an error :

```
    API Error Code: 191
    API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
    Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.
```

In application, there is no .htaccess file for redirecting or removing index.php in root directory.

I have run this base controller code :

```
    public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("session");
    $this->load->helper('cookie');

    parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_REQUEST );
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
    $config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
    $this->load->library('Facebook', $config);

}

/**
 * Index function
 * @access public
 * 
public function index()
{
    $userId = $this->facebook->getUser();
    // If user is not yet authenticated, the id will be zero

    if($userId == 0){
                    // Generate a login url
        $params = array(
                  'scope' => 'email,user_about_me, user_birthday, user_location');
        $url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>" . "top.location.href = '" . $url. "';</script>";
        }
    }
```

When i print '$url' then redirect_url in query string is 'http://in9.hostgator.in/~username/', not redirect to https path.

I am confused, what is a mistake in code? or some wrong configuration in server or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook applications have an "App Domains" setting too, the facebook sdk won't work if the canvas url's are not under the listed domains. Try to add both the `example.org` and the `hostgator.in` there.

Alternatively you can use the facebook canvas url as the redirect uri, so if your facebook app's namespace is `my-facebook-app` then you can generate the login url like this:

```
$this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'email,user_about_me, user_birthday, user_location',
    // change the last segment to you app's namespace
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/my-facebook-app/'
));
```

With canvas applications this probably more feasible since because if the redirect uri points directly to your secure canvas url, the users will "loose" facebook when they authenticate.

Comment: this is not possible because when facebook app redirect to server then again he get same url (app), So it have a recursive redirect problem.

Comment: @Rajnish, in the sample code, the redirection only take place when the application is not yet installed (guarded with a `if($userId == 0)` so the redirection should stop once the user installs the app.

Comment: But when i have put this code in CI- controller, it goes on redirection..for that cas can you give how we prevent redirection. I have also echo script for installing user profile.

Comment: Just wrap the redirection inside an if like `if (!$this->facebook->getUser()) { ... }`. When facebook sends back the browser after successful install, the app will get the active facebook user's id in the signed request so the `getUser()` call will return something non zero, so you can branch on that and skip the redirection.

Comment: I have do exactly same as you mention but still it's redirect recursively.

Comment: You probably have some other problem as well then that prevents parsing the provided signed request and extracting the user id, check app domain and the app secret. Also, if the user choose **not** to install the app then yes the code will send her back to the install page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27786/discussion-between-rajnish-and-complex857)